# Go to fullscreen and back in directX

Tags: c++, directx

I'm now learning how to use directX (10 - 11), and i use materials from SDK samples, http://www.rastertek.com/ and http://takinginitiative.net/category/graphics-programming/directx-10-tutorials.
But i find it suprising that none has explainded the transition between fullscreen and windowed. I also seached with google, in GameDevelopment and StackOverflow, but no result.

What i'm asking is explanation or full exaples for both Window and DirectX "classes".

Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using the normal Windows API function `ChangeDisplaySettings` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183411(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Not with D3D10/11 - use IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState instead.

Comment: @mh01, I've used this tutorial http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html and double checked the source code for this answer, any reason why you shouldn't use the Windows API functions? They seem to work fine when I test it.

Comment: Mostly because SetFullScreenState is the method documented by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Choosing_the_DXGI_Output_and_Size.  It's generally good to follow the documentation I think, and the documentation should take precedence over a tutorial.

Comment: there is nothing against using both. if you start your app and don't have a DirectX context yet, a lot of 3D Applications use ChangeDisplaySettings right after the window has been created to go fullscreen, and as soon as a context is available use SetFullScreenState for further adjustements

Comment: @cppanda so once you have a DirectX context ChangeDisplaySettings no longer works? Should you use mh01's solution once you've already have a DirectX context? (In that case I think his answer is indeed better)

Answer (score 1):

It actually turned out even simpler, I just recreated  the DirectX device (or reset it) using new presentation parameters (windowed = false).

Comment: Doesn't recreating the DirectX device have negative affects (maybe losing track of what is in GPU memory, I'm not sure but someone might be).